# new in tensorflow and keras for image processing and detection using nural network

Tags: python-3.x, keras, neural-network, tensorflow2.0

is there any wizard for nural-network that write python code(tensorflow) for image processing and detection?
I am new in this field and usually I learn faster with simpler codes...

Comment: To the best of my knowledge, there is no "wizard" for implementing neural nets. However, both `Keras` and `Tensorflow` have pretty extensive documentation pages that would be a great starting point.

Answer (score 0):

This [doc](https://www.tensorflow.org/tutorials/images/classification) may be the answer .
Just read it .